# Mapping Using R

Tags: r, mapping

i have an annoying problem with my code,

i'm from Philippines. I have no problem With the Filter Code for mapping  the Shape file of US like this ..

nhgeo <- filter(usgeo, STATEFP=="33")

then i used the code to Philippines shape file which i downloaded but it gives me the error..

> phgeo <- filter(phgeo, stateFP =='9807')
>   Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
>     Evaluation error: object 'stateFP' not found.

is there any idea why?

hope my problem will be solve by you

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's your letter case as stateFP is fully capitalized in your first line of code, but isn't in your second. Try this

```
   phgeo <- filter(phgeo, STATEFP == '9807')
```